# How to download youtube videos for iphone - using objective-c programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, download, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save Youtube video to iPhone in the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087249/save-youtube-video-to-iphone-in-the-app)

I want to download and save a youtube video from a given youtube video link, programmatically. Can anyone point to some sample app. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the AVAssetWriter class help you at all?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Not a problem with writing or saving, but I need to download them programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Check out which URL and algorithm I used: https://github.com/H2CO3/PwnTube

Answer (score 0):

Not a problem:

[Here is my example:](https://github.com/comonitos/youtube_video)

I used PSYouTubeExtractor.h class by Peter Steinberger It can get youtube mp4 video url and than downloading and viewing is not a problem

Comment: It was taking Too much time. I set 3o seconds video URL in your code But still after half hour it was not downloaded.