# Is it possible to download video from youtube from my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, ios, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save Youtube video to iPhone in the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087249/save-youtube-video-to-iphone-in-the-app)

I want to download youtube video from my iPhone application, is it possible? If so, then provide code for how to do it.

Comment: I'm guessing it's not possible, even if you can achieve it the videos are usually converted into `.flv` or `webM` which i don't think is supported in ios. Posting as a comment as i'm not sure, would like to know this myself.

Comment: "If so, then provide code for how to do it" - Yeah. Sure. We'll do your work for you....

Comment: Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

I once read in a blog that recently google blocked all apps that try to download video from youtube because it violates its terms and conditions. Just try to check that and confirm whether you can achieve it or not.

But there is objective-c client for handling the youtube.

Check this library http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

This is for objective-C but if you wanna port it to ios this link may be halpful
http://johntwang.com/blog/2009/06/08/how-to-use-google-apis-with-iphone-sdk/