# How to download youtube video with youtube url in iphone programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save Youtube video to iPhone in the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087249/save-youtube-video-to-iphone-in-the-app)

Is there any sdk or way to download youtube video with youtube url in iphone programmatically.

Please help me out for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to release that app to AppStore I wouldn't advise you to leave that option. Youtube rules are not permitting that and Apple is following them very much these days although there are apps on AppStore that have that functionality enabled. One of my friends tried to add offline play to his Youtube player app and got rejected because of it.

Comment: Hi Amar,

Can you please guide where this thing is documented. So that i can show to my team.

Thanks,

Comment: here is their rejection message - http://cl.ly/image/2n01111Z1g1k

Comment: Also on this link you can read their Terms of Service - http://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms and I think under 5.B you can find something like "you shouldn't download any content that doesn't have download now link" or something like that

Comment: @AmarKulo i also want to download videos from `youtube` and i think appple would not mind it because there are already apps which gives this facility. [ProTube](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/protuber-best-player-for-youtube/id643857858?mt=8) and this [MyTube](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/mytube-for-youtube-free-video/id580838020?mt=8) how to download video?

Comment: Although my answer was almost year ago, the fact that there are apps on the AppStore that are breaking rules doesn't mean that all of us should do it. Google can ask Apple to remove every single of them and Apple will do that. So you can do it, no question about it, but the question is how long will you do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
   1) Get the NSURL Object First using url string.   
   2) Allocate and start an NSURLConnection to fetch the file from the URL. Do not use sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error      
   3) In the connection:didReceiveResponse: delegate method, create NSData object
   4) In the connection:didReceiveData: delegate method, get the data and append it to NSData object
   5) play the video using MPMoviePlayerController after getting data.
```