# How to download video from youtube and also trim or cut that downloaded video in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, video, youtube

I want to download video from `youtube`. Then the downloaded video should saved and user can also play it in offline mode and user can also trim or edit that downloaded video.

I have searched a lot on Google and i find some answers but they didn't satisfy my question.

[This question tell downloading video from youtube may reject your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068538/how-to-download-youtube-video-with-youtube-url-in-iphone-programmatically) is this true?

[The screen shot from apple](http://cl.ly/image/2n01111Z1g1k). [YouTube Terms & Condition](http://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms) are also not allowing to download videos. **Read section 5-B.**

I have also try to load some examples for video downloading from youtube but they all failed for loading video [MyTube](https://github.com/iosdeveloper/MyTube) , [YouTube](https://github.com/comonitos/youtube_video) , [SCBTube](https://github.com/pkjmesra/SCBUTube) , [PSYouTubeExtractor](https://github.com/steipete/PSYouTubeExtractor)

[Some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803628/how-to-download-the-youtube-video-and-save-it-using-objective-c) related to youtube download. and for video trimming or cutting i am following [this code](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios) .

is this downloading is possible or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Downloading is, in some cases, possible, but it's against the YouTube T&Cs...so yeah, don't do it. Furthermore, even if you did implement this not all videos on YouTube are actually available in the appropriate H.264 format (e.g, videos which require advertising or content protection are often not available).

Comment: ok than how can i check that the downloading is available or the format is H.264 before downloading video? and how this application actually works for downloading videos? https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/mytube-for-youtube-free-video/id580838020?mt=8