# Download YouTube videos doesn't work

Tags: url, youtube

I parsed the "url_encoded_fmt_stream_map=" entries with the direct video urls of some formats, example (decoded):

```
http://r7---sn-2apm-f5f6.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?gcr=de&cp=U0hUTFVUUl9LUENONF9NTlZHOkpGR0NWdWtvSk15&source=youtube&ip=46.59.194.67&upn=KHmKgXE5di4&fexp=917000,906357,911115,916611,920704,912806,928001,922403,922405,929901,913605,929104,913546,913556,908496,920201,913302,919009,911116,901451,902556&ms=au&itag=45&mt=1357571596&sparams=cp,gcr,id,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&id=e4b675c403014739&expire=1357594666&ipbits=8&mv=m&newshard=yes&ratebypass=yes&sver=3&key=yt1&signature=1C8204D1180CAB0B57E3B3331409BD055CBA25B1.73FBEC95E020BBCAC6485D62601E8CF05ACA72DE,quality=hd720&itag=22&fallback_host=tc.v23.cache2.c.youtube.com&type=video/mp4;+codecs="avc1.64001F,+mp4a.40.2"
```

But I can't download or view it! VLC says: Cannot open! Firefox remains empty (white window, no error message)! Are the urls after "url_encoded_fmt_stream_map=" right?

Comment: I'm also interested in that. I tried this approach and got the same result. Could someone provide a current working solution for downloading Youtube videos?

Comment: you can also just download the video from youtube to your local storage first. check this out, it's really helpful: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-Wbjmm980A

Answer (score 0):

In my answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14352995/307547   I described a solution for downloading youtube videos.

```
LBYouTubeExtractor *extractor = [[[LBYouTubeExtractor alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:(@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@"), self.videoID ]] quality:LBYouTubeVideoQualityLarge] autorelease];
[extractor extractVideoURLWithCompletionBlock:^(NSURL *videoURL, NSError *error) {
    if(!error) {
        NSLog(@"Did extract video URL using completion block: %@", videoURL);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: videoURL];
            NSString *pathToDocs = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"video_%@.mp4"), self.videoID ];
            [data writeToFile:[pathTODocs stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] atomically:YES];
            NSLog(@"File %@ successfully saved", filename);
        });
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed extracting video URL using block due to error:%@", error);
    }
}];
```

You can show progress of downloading using technique described in the posts above.
You can replace dataWithContentsOfURL with more appropriate for you method.

Comment: So are we allowed to directly download the video or is it against the tos ? Also the quality is low for some reason :(