# How to download a video from youtube in application?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to download youtube video from my iPhone application. I am not sure is it possible or not.

If possible, then give me some ideas and also let me know what would be the format of that video after downloading. I have failed to do the same.

Comment: Have you tried HCYouTube Parser to download video?

Comment: Can You please provide me the code.I have no idea on it.

Comment: @Tapash Can you not use google to search for yourself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save Youtube video to iPhone in the app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087249/save-youtube-video-to-iphone-in-the-app)

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser

use this code for play youtube video on your app

> Warning: This is not approved by the ToC of YouTube. Use at own risk.

Comment: I just added it in to show that it is to be used at their own risk +1 though

Answer (score 0):

Whilst `2014` answer would work and does come with a warning to use at your own risk. From this morning I wouldn't bother doing this anymore. Apple have started removing Apps that allow users to download music from sources like YouTube. So unfortunately `2014`s answer has actually become redundant.

One of these apps that have been removed is YouTubes own app.

This is believed to be a move to push users to use the new iTunes Radio app and the iTunes store for downloading music.

Here are a couple of sources

http://www.macrumors.com/2014/06/10/apple-removing-music-downloading-apps/

http://www.imore.com/apple-removes-apps-music-download-capabilities-its-app-store