# How to play youtube videos in a native player and also how to download youtube videos

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

I am creating one application, in that i need to  play youtube videos in a native player and also  download youtube videos into application. please help me in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = @"<html><head><style>body{margin:0;}</style></head> <body> <div id=\"player\"></div> <script> var tag = document.createElement('script'); tag.src = 'http://www.youtube.com/player_api'; var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag); var player; function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { player = new YT.Player('player', { width:\'100%%\', height:'339px', videoId:\'%@\', events: { 'onReady': onPlayerReady } }); } function onPlayerReady(event) { event.target.playVideo(); } </script> </body> </html>";



NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeVideoHTML, videoId];

videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0f, 247.0f, 743.0f, 339.0f)];
videoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
videoView.opaque = NO;
videoView.scrollView.scrollEnabled=NO;

// videoView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:videoView];

videoView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;

[videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

Answer (score 0):

To grab the url / download the video help should be available here: [Save Youtube video to iPhone in the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087249/save-youtube-video-to-iphone-in-the-app).

If you have the direct video url you could stream it with the native [MPMoviePlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:youTubeDirectURL];

[mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
[mp setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming];
[mp setFullscreen:YES];

[self.view addSubview:mp.view];

[mp prepareToPlay];
[mp play];
```

[Apple MoviePlayer example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html)