# How to download video from youtube and save (objective c)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, youtube-data-api, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

How can I download videos from you-tube and save in my app folder. I have `videoID`, but don't have working code. I found this link but the code from this link is not working for me.

[Save Youtube video to iPhone in the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087249/save-youtube-video-to-iphone-in-the-app)

If any one have any working code please share it with me thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set your youtube  url

```
- (void)downloadMultiAFN:(NSString *)userIDFrom messageId:(NSString *)msgId message:(NSString *)message url:(NSString *)url contact:(NSString *) contact nickName:(NSString *)nickName  {
    imageUrlPathForSharingMessgeId=msgId;

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *downloadRequest = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [downloadRequest setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:responseObject];

// you can save video or image with avi or png  
      //  [[DBManagernew getSharedInstance] saveDataUploadImage:msgId isRead:NO isSend:YES isReceipt:NO image:data];
      //  imageIsSelected=NO;
  // [self fetchAllMessage];



    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"file downloading error : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];

    [downloadRequest start];


}
```

Comment: My url for video is this "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAlbIwwxVCw" . Its 3.12 sec video but when i  your method with this url i receive only 180244 byte=180 kb in data. Mean there is some problem with this because when i write it in file system its not opening. do you have any idea what will be the problem?

Comment: set your time session requesting time

Comment: response object =<OS_dispatch_data: data[0x16eccc00] = { leaf, size = 192258, buf = 0x1e32000 }>

Comment: "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";

Comment: Actually i'm new on objective c. How can i set time session requesting time?

Comment: [request setTimeoutInterval:120]; ?? is it ok

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101975/discussion-between-nisar-ahmad-and-raj-yadav).

Comment: i have try with request time 3600 but still not working :(

Comment: Can you please try to convert the data into NSString and check that string, it returns html file.

Comment: is it working? looks like its downloading the html data page.